# Is it possible to add localization to pre-compiled framework?

Tags: ios

I'm using a binary framework in my iOS project. This project is only available in english, but I would like to localize it. Assuming the original author used NSLocalizedString everywhere, is it possible to localize this framework "from the outside"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible putting the translations in the Localizable.strings file. It should be easy to try...

If it does not work, sometimes libraries include a localizable strings file in a bundle. Then you should put your translations there.